# Run two python files at the same time

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scripting

I have tried using

```
#!/bin/bash
python ScriptA.py &
python ScriptB.py &
```

to run both scripts at the same time but it always returns "Invalid Syntax" with ScriptA even though all python files are in the same folder.

File that runs both scripts:

```
def song():
user = input()
    if user == "Chance":
        python ScriptA.py &
        python ScriptB.py &
   else:
        print("Error")
```

The solutions i found so far, such as putting that script in one line, doesn't work as the error still shows.

--------------------------EDIT--------------------------

Both scripts run fine individually however, all the solutions you have provided still run sequentially. Script A is a video that plays via OpenCV and Script B is a song that plays via playsound.

ScriptA:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if ret == True:
    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break
  else:
    break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

ScriptB:

```
from playsound import playsound
a = (r"C:\Users\A\Desktop\sound.mp3")
playsound(a)
```

As you may tell, i'm trying to display a song alongside a video. I tried to display a video that has sound but openCV doesn't output sound for some reason. Any suggestions?

Comment: Both scrips are working fine when you execute them individually?

Comment: What language is that second code snippet?  Or, rather, what language is it intended to be?  It is invalid syntax in both sh and python.

Comment: @Mufeed asks the right questions. "Invalid Syntax" error has nothing to do with files being in the same folder. Probably you have a python syntax error in your ScriptA.py , as your provided python script also has syntax error in it.

Comment: To clarify, both scripts work perfectly fine when executed individually.

Comment: Due to GIL(Global Interpreter Lock) in python only one thread can run at a given time, check this out [threads not able to reduce the run time of two function when run at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58005044/threads-not-able-to-reduce-the-run-time-of-two-function-when-run-at-once)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are looking for multi-threading

you could merge your both script into another script,
then lauch them using theads

**--edit--**

```
from threading import Thread

import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from playsound import playsound

def play_sound(): 
    # import your script A
    a = (r"C:\Users\A\Desktop\sound.mp3")
    playsound(a)

def CV2_stuff():
    # import your script B
    os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
    ...


Thread(target = play_sound).start() 
Thread(target = CV2_stuff).start()
```

hope it helps

this could work too

```
import ScriptA
import ScriptB

ScriptA.function()
ScriptB.function()
```

but they wouldn't be exectuted in the same time

Comment: I tried that but still no luck, i have edited my original post to help clarify my situation

Comment: My soltion here would be to make one script with 2 functions, then call them with theards, i'll edit my post too :)

Comment: Thank you so much Peko, it works! Now all i have to do is figure out how to loop the video until the song ends so the video can end and return to another script

Answer (score 3):

You have to import `os` module and use the `system` function from it, then separate the two Python files you are running by `&&`.

```
import os
def song():
    user = input()
    if user == "Chance":
        os.system('python ScriptA.py && python ScriptB.py')
    else:
        print("Error")

song()
```

But I will advice you to just import the two files you want to run into the third file and just run the functions in there like normal functions.

e.g.

```
import ScriptA
import ScriptB

ScriptA.function()
ScriptB.function()
```

If there are no functions inside the scripts, the script runs immediately after they are imported.

Comment: this will not run them parallelly as intended by OP. You should probably call the functions in two different threads.

Comment: As penguin stated, it does not run parallel, i have included more information in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can try os.system :

```
import os

os.system("python ScriptA.py &")
os.system("python ScriptB.py &")
```

Comment: I tried that and it sill shows sequentially. I have updated my original post to help understand what i am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can just open both files on the python IDLE and run each o them.
If you need both files to run simultaneously (the first way you have the delay of pressing F5 on each file) you can use PyCharm and download the *multirun* plugin.