# import python script to other and run both in the same time

Tags: python

I have two python files `first.py` and `second.py`, want both work in the same time
so i tried to use this module import file

```
import first.py 
import second.py
```

but one only of them is working.

how to run both in the same time?

**---EDIT---**

i tried multi-threading and

but still no luck :(, still one of two only is working

**---EDIT---**

solved it was Indentation Error

Comment: Take a look at the `threading` module. Anyway, in order for your question to be answered, please clarify your question editing the answer and providing more information.

Comment: i think this may be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875889/run-two-python-files-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use threading and subprocess like this:

```
import threading
import subprocess
import sys

def run_process(path):
    cmd = 'python %s' % path
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
        sys.stdout.write(line)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=run_process, args=('path_to_first.py',))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=run_process, args=('path_to_second.py',))

#start
t1.start()
t2.start()

# Waiting
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Comment: Running a second Python instance in a `subprocess` seems excessive. Just give the second thread a function within the other module to run.