# threads not able to reduce the run time of two function when run at once

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have two functions `f1` and `f2` which increment an integer specific number of times in a loop inside these two functions.

Two ways I call these functions.

1) One by one, that is first `f1` then `f2`.
2) Create a thread `t1` to run function `f1` and thread `t2` to run function `f2`.

As soon in the code below, I have tried both the ways.

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import datetime
from queue import Queue

def f1(a):
    for i in range(1,100000000):
        a+=1
    return a

def f2(a):
    for i in range(1,100000000):
        a+=1
    return a
if __name__ == '__main__':

    que1 = Queue()
    que2 = Queue()

    # t2 = Thread(target=f1(a),name='t2')
    a = 0
    s_t = time.time()
    print('Value of a, before calling function f1: ',a)
    a=f1(a)
    print('Value of a, after calling function f1: ',a)
    a = 0
    print('Value of a, before calling function f2: ',a)
    a=f2(a)
    print('Value of a, after calling function f2: ',a)
    print('Time taken without threads: ',datetime.timedelta(seconds=time.time()-s_t))

    s_t = time.time()
    a = 0
    print('Value of a, before calling function f1 through thread t1: ',a)

    t1 = Thread(target=lambda q, arg1: q.put(f1(arg1)), args=(que1,a),name = 't1')
    print('Value of a, before calling function f2 through thread t2: ',a)

    t2 = Thread(target=lambda q, arg1: q.put(f2(arg1)), args=(que2,a),name = 't2')

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    print('Value of a, after calling function f1 through thread t1: ',que1.get())
    t2.join()
    print('Value of a, after calling function f2 through thread t2: ',que2.get())
    print('Time taken with threads: ',datetime.timedelta(seconds=time.time()-s_t))
```

Expected threads to do the jobs faster than calling the functions one after the other but it's not the case here.

Here's the output

```
Value of a, before calling function f1:  0
Value of a, after calling function f1:  99999999
Value of a, before calling function f2:  0
Value of a, after calling function f2:  99999999
Time taken without threads:  0:00:07.623239
Value of a, before calling function f1 through thread t1:  0
Value of a, before calling function f2 through thread t2:  0
Value of a, after calling function f1 through thread t1:  99999999
Value of a, after calling function f2 through thread t2:  99999999
Time taken with threads:  0:00:27.274876
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: In `python`, only a `single` `thread` can run at a `time`, because of the `GIL(Global Interpreter Lock)`. So you running `thread`s for `cpu` intensive operation is `useless` in `python`

Comment: @hansolo can you suggest a work around?

Comment: You can use `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` as a work around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **python**, only a **single thread** can run at **a time**, because of the **GIL(Global Interpreter Lock)**. [What is a GIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython). So running threads for cpu intensive operation is not very useful in python. But threads are great for I/O. I hope, i clarified :)

Assuming `python3`, you could use `ProcessPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures` like,

```
$ cat cpuintense.py
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def f1(a):
    for i in range(1,100000000):
        a+=1
    return a

def f2(a):
    for i in range(1,100000000):
        a+=1
    return a

def run_in_sequence(a):
    start = time.time()
    f1(a)
    f2(a)
    end = time.time()
    print(f'[Sequential] Took {end-start} seconds')

def run_in_parallel(a):
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as pool:
        start = time.time()
        fut1 = pool.submit(f1, a)
        fut2 = pool.submit(f2, a)
        for fut in (fut1, fut2):
            print(fut.result())
        end = time.time()
        print(f'[Parallel] Took {end-start} seconds')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 0
    run_in_sequence(a)
    run_in_parallel(a)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 cpuintense.py
[Sequential] Took 6.838468790054321 seconds
99999999
99999999
[Parallel] Took 3.488879919052124 seconds
```

Note: The `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard is required for windows. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) the reason is,

> Since Windows lacks os.fork() it has a few extra restrictions:
>
> Safe importing of main module
>
> ```
> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a new process).
>
> For example, under Windows running the following module would fail with a RuntimeError:
>
> from multiprocessing import Process
>
> def foo():
>     print 'hello'
>
> p = Process(target=foo)
> p.start()
>
> Instead one should protect the “entry point” of the program by using if __name__ == '__main__': as follows:
>
> from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support
>
> def foo():
>     print 'hello'
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     freeze_support()
>     p = Process(target=foo)
>     p.start()
>
> (The freeze_support() line can be omitted if the program will be run normally instead of frozen.)
>
> This allows the newly spawned Python interpreter to safely import the module and then run the module’s foo() function.
>
> Similar restrictions apply if a pool or manager is created in the main module.
> ```

Comment: I get this error when i run your code `concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.`

Comment: Same code that you have suggested in your answer, as it is.

Comment: @SanthoshDhaipuleChandrakanth That's weird :/. Could you paste the code and the traceback ?

Comment: You can check it in my question

Comment: I'm running Python 3.7.4 on WIndows,

Comment: @SanthoshDhaipuleChandrakanth Are you running on windows too ?

Comment: Yup ran on `python 3.7.2` and `python 3.6.4` on Windows 10 same error

Comment: Okay. I see there's some `guard` issue in `windows` [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900366/all-example-concurrent-futures-code-is-failing-with-brokenprocesspool). Could you run with the updated code ?

Comment: Something else weird is that before the error occurs, two `[Sequential] Took xxx.xx seconds` messaged are printed with slightly different values.

Comment: @martineau Oh, interesting. Let me see if i can get any windows to run this code

Comment: It will work if you put the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard in before the last three statements (and indent them).

Comment: @martineau. Yeah, already updated. It is weird. One of the interesting things i came across yet :)

Comment: It's because of how processes are started on Windows (which is different than on *nixes).